# Difference between RAM and internal storage chips in HTC Sensation

Tags: memory, ram

Just having a small discussion at work about my [HTC Sensation](http://www.htc.com/us/products/sensation4g-tmobile/#tech-specs) phone. My question is: is there a difference (in chips) that are used for *internal storage* and *RAM memory*?

Must they be using other chips? Can't they be both the same flash chip with a partition? Is there a speed difference between the chips?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When talking about internal memory in mobile phones they usually mean Flash memory. This is the memory which holds your system software (operating system and such) and the applications. This memory is non-volatile, which means that data is retained even when power is switched off. That's what you want, otherwise your phone would become worthless if the battery is drained.

RAM is volatile memory, which means that the content is gone when the power is switched off. This is used by the OS and the applications to hold their temporary content, which becomes irrelevant if the device is switched off and/or which easily can be reconstructed.

Comment: So they must be using other chips? They cannot be both the same flash chip with a partition?

Comment: Looks like it is using a http://www.stericsson.com/products/u9500-novathor.jsp

Comment: @Kees - Yes, they're different chips. The technology is completely different. RAM can be written an unlimited number of times, while for Flash this is limited. RAM is also faster. Both properties make that you don't want Flash for continuously changing data, that's why they use RAM and not a partition of the Flash chips.

Answer (score 2):

The 4GB internal memory is non-volatile storage. This means it can be used to store photos, mp3s, etc. When you switch the phone off, the photos won't vanish.

The RAM is volatile memory, and cannot be used to store photos. It's used by the applications as they are running.